# I want to save the user data in the list of uitextfields

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to save all the data the user has put in the UITextFields, to save when the app is quited and to reload the data when the user comes back to it.

Comment: Unclear question. So whats the problem?

Comment: For something like this, NSUserDefaults is probably the best choice.

Answer (score 0):

Extract strings from each UITextFields and store it in strings or in a class.

Then you have multiple options to save it like :

[Plist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905542/how-to-write-data-in-plist).

[CoreData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902958/good-core-data-tutorial).

[Normal File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933255/saving-files-in-cocoa).